# Match two dfs based on conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs: dfname (which has different versions of names of player) and dfgoals which has information about the player and their goals scored.
I want to return one row for each player in the answer df based on a condition:

(i) see if name1 value exists in actual_name col in dfgoals and if it does, return the first matched row, otherwise check name2 value and return the first matched row

(ii) whichever value is matched (name1 or name2) return the name col value from dfname as well

```
dfname = pd.DataFrame({
                     "name": ["ryan", "bill", "saka", "Henry","Rooney"], 
                     "name1": ["ryan 112", "Bill Matt Cdevaca", "Bukayo Saka", "Super Henry","Rooney"], 
                     "name2": ["NaN", "XXVaca", "Bukayo", "Thierry","Rooney"]})



dfgoals = pd.DataFrame({
                     "actual_name": ["ryan 112", "XXVaca", "Bukayo", "Thierry", "Ronaldo", "Messi"], 
                     "goals": [0, 2, 5, 10, 100, 200], 
                     "matches": [22, 100, 200, 300, 100, 90]})


answerdf = pd.DataFrame({
                     "actual_name": ["ryan 112", "XXVaca", "Bukayo", "Thierry", "Rooney"], 
                     "goals": [0, 2, 5, 10, "NaN"], 
                     "matches": [22, 100, 200, 300, "NaN"],
                    "name_from_dfname": ["ryan", "bill", "saka", "Henry", "Rooney"]})
answerdf

Rooney's values are NaN because his goals record is not available
```

I have tried this so far but it does not check for name1-2 values correctly, for example it gives me only ryan's goals and not other player's because their names are mentioned differently

```
df = dfgoals
values_to_check = ['ryan', 'Bill Matt Cdevaca', 'saka', 'henry', 'Rooney']

filtered_rows = []

# Iterate through the DataFrame rows to find matches and concatenate values
for index, row in dfgoals.iterrows():
    matched_values = [value for value in values_to_check if value.lower() in row['actual_name'].lower()]
    if matched_values:
        row['concatenated_values'] = '|'.join(matched_values)
        filtered_rows.append(row)

# Create a new DataFrame from the filtered rows
result_df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_rows)
result_df['concatenated_values'] = pd.Categorical(result_df['concatenated_values'], categories=values_to_check, ordered=True)

# Sort the DataFrame based on the 'concatenated_values' column
result_df.sort_values(by = "concatenated_values")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `.stack` the `dfname` and then set index of the new dataframe from the  values of `name1`/`name2` columns. Then use `.map`:

```py
x = dfname.set_index('name').stack().reset_index().dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=0).set_index(0)['name']
dfgoals['name_from_dfname'] = dfgoals['actual_name'].map(x)
```

Prints:

```
  actual_name  goals  matches name_from_dfname
0    ryan 112      0       22             ryan
1      XXVaca      2      100             bill
2      Bukayo      5      200             saka
3     Thierry     10      300            Henry
```

---

EDIT: To add missing players:

```py
x = dfname.set_index('name').stack().reset_index().dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=0).set_index(0)['name']
dfgoals['name_from_dfname'] = dfgoals['actual_name'].map(x)

# add missing players
missing_players = dfname.loc[~dfname['name'].isin(dfgoals['name_from_dfname']), ['name']].rename(columns={'name': 'actual_name'})
missing_players['name_from_dfname'] = missing_players['actual_name']

dfgoals = pd.concat([dfgoals, missing_players])
print(dfgoals)
```

Prints:

```
  actual_name  goals  matches name_from_dfname
0    ryan 112    0.0     22.0             ryan
1      XXVaca    2.0    100.0             bill
2      Bukayo    5.0    200.0             saka
3     Thierry   10.0    300.0            Henry
4     Ronaldo  100.0    100.0              NaN
5       Messi  200.0     90.0              NaN
4      Rooney    NaN      NaN           Rooney
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked initially but there is an entry like Rooney which is repeated in other name cols, it does not work.

Comment: @AAA Can you please [edit] your question and update the sample input with multiple names (e.g "Rooney") and what should be the expected result?

Comment: Done! Sorry for not being clear earlier.

Comment: @AAA I've edited my answer. Added `.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Rooney is not returned actually, but I want it returned with nan in goals and matches cols.